# Customizing container for Android UI elements

Tags: android-fragments, android

I'm trying to style my android application and new to styling UI elements. I'd like to create a custom UI container which looks like the following:

[image: Example]

I.e. the container draws the arrow shape around the content. I'm also hoping to have the feature such the the arrow end of the container will scale nicely according to the height of the content (so possibly using vector graphics), but this is less crucial.

After spending most of the day playing around with the UI with no success, I thought I'd ask for help here. I've tried playing around with custom UI elements, using the drawable right property, the background property and trying to construct it out of other elements.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to draw the arrow shaped container yourself. You could use a transparent png and set it as a background for the container. e.g your xml should roughly look like this:

```
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/container_layout"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/arrow_shaped_transparent_png">

         <!-- The rest of the stuff goes in here e.g a textview in your case -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With this solution, won't the content spill over the designated container (in grey), also even if I were to add suitable padding, then the arrow head still wouldn't stretch nicely, I'd like the turns to be 45 degrees, so the arrow should get longer if the content increases in height.